# Different intervals for setTimeout in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I am trying to achieve a situation when a function inside setTimeout is executed after X seconds **first time**, and then regularly at Y interval.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    let firstTime = true;
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      getValue(id).then((res) => {
        setValue(res);
      });
      if (firstTime) {
        firstTime = false;
      }
    }, firstTime ? 30000 : 60000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [])
```

This doesn't work, however, as it sets `firstTime` to false before running the function. Is there a way to graciously achieve the result? Is it even possible with `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variable as the `setTimeout` delay. In this case you would set `firstTime` to the delay you wanted to use the first time (30000), and then inside timer you would use `if (firstTime == 30000) { firstTime = 60000; }`. Using a different variable name here would make sense. Then set the `setTimeout` delay to just `firstTime` like `}, firstTime);`

Hopefully this is actually what you wanted.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let firstTime = 30000;
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      getValue(id).then((res) => {
        setValue(res);
      });
      if (firstTime == 30000) {
        firstTime = 60000;
      }
    }, firstTime);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [])
```

Old (incorrect) answer:

You can use `setTimeout` with an initial delay to initialise a `setInterval`, which will repeat subsequent times at a different interval.

Comment: Do you mean nesting setInterval within setTimeout?

Comment: Exactly, the setTimeout will run once after the first delay (30000), and then you can nest a `setInterval` to run every 60000ms. However, reading the question again, that might not be what you are after.

Comment: Basically, I'd like to setValue first after 30 seconds, and then after every 60 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, I actually got the result with your old answer. Can't quite figure out the new one, so would appreciate if you can add some code here. Gonna mark your answer right, though.

Comment: I added the code I was describing to the answer

Comment: Thanks, your code doesn't work, but I will still keep the correct answer mark, since I as able to achieve what I wanted with your hint. Unless someone else proposes a more gracious solution.